# Wildcard operator in system verilog and its synthesizability

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

what are Wildcard operators in system  verilog? I have searched the net but there is some ambiguity.

Also are they synthesizable?

Answers for below?

```
4'b1010 ==? 4'b10x0 
4'b10x0 ==? 4'b1010
```

Comment: An answer to the first part of the question could be found in any verilog tutorial or documentation. The second part about synthesizability is  interesting and i vote for re-opening the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't search the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). Section *11.4.6 Wildcard equality operators* defines this operator. A search would give many other examples like [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/how-use-system-verilog).

Wildcard equality operators are intended to be synthesizable as long as the X appears on the RHS as a literal or constant expression. X's on the RHS are treated as don't care matches. X's on the LHS do not match anything and only used in simulation. The `inside` operator and the `case inside` conditional statement all use this asymmetric wildcard matching for synthesizable don't cares.

Answer (score 0):

From section 5.5 of "IEEE Standard for Verilog Register Transfer Level Synthesis" IEEE Std 1364.1-2002 (1364 is the base specification that IEEE-1800 extended, and 1361.1 defined the synthesizable subset of 1364):

```
The value x may be used in case item expressions (may be mixed 
with other expressions, such as 4'b01x0) in a casex statement to 
imply a don't care value for synthesis.
```

As the Wildcard operator is an obvious extension of the casex expression, one would reasonably expect that it is intended to be synthesizable.  I am not aware of an IEEE standard for 1800 that defines the synthesizable subset; or if this information is contained in the IEEE-1800 standard itself.

The late Stuart Sutherland proposed a list of synthesizable constructs for IEEE-1800 which included the Wildcard Equality, in his paper: https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-DVCon_SystemVerilog_synthesis_subset_paper.pdf

As a matter of practicality, the definitive way to check such a question is code up a small example using this construct, and feed it to the synthesis tool you are actually planning to use and see if you get warnings, errors, or working code!